# Creating a variable based on previous clicked link in jekyll

Tags: javascript, html, jekyll

I have a jekyll based site running, I want to display a page when clicked on the hyperlinked tag links. According to the name of the tag link clicked, I want to generate the page, i.e. I want to have one page for all the tags being clicked, its just the name of the hyperlinked text that is clicked, that should decide the value of a variable in the liquid html code of the new page. How can I achieve this? Currently I am storing multiple copies of the same code, just differing on the value of one variable, very high redundancy !

eg: Suppose my site has a hyperlinked text as : `hello` , the next page that it should open should use this word (`hello`) in one of the variables, is it possible?

Comment: So you want Jekyll to dynamically generate the page depending on what was clicked?

Comment: Ya, I dont know its possible or not

Comment: Jekyll is for generating static sites, you would have to generate all the possible pages in advance.

Comment: Ok, I thought so :(